# Calling funtion in a C++ Shared Library from Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, wrapper, swig

I have implemented a Java code that calls a C++ shared library named math (libmath.so). However, when I try to call a function that is implemented by the library, I get the an error:

> libmath.so: undefined symbol: lt_dlinit

Any guidance on this?

The Java code:

```
public class runme 
{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("math");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load\n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

 public static void main(String argv[]) 
 {
    System.out.println( "Hello and welcome to test_program." );

   //assuming that I have NumberVectr filled correctly. 
   NumbersVectr numbers = new NumberVectr(10);
   for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
   {
      numbers.add((Number)i);  
   }

    //Now, the problem I am having is in invoking the library
    //MathematicsWrapper is a Java wrapper class that wraps the original Mathematics class implemented in C++. 
    //compute is an arbitrary function implemented in the original C++ class, which itself loads another native library once instantiated.
    MathematicsWrapper myMaths = new MathematicsWrapper();
        myMaths.compute(numbers); 
 }
}
```

The original C++  Mathematics class looks like this:

```
class MathematicsWrapper 
{
public:

  MathematicsWrapper ()
  {
    load_library("math_core.so");
  };

  ~MathematicsWrapper (){
    unload_library();
  };

  int compute(std::vector<int> &numbers);
```

I have the following output:

> Hello and welcome to test_program.
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error:
>   /home/kevin/test_prgram/src/libmath.so:
>   undefined symbol: lt_dlinit

The MathematicsWrapper is defined as:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 3.0.9
 *
 * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
 * the SWIG interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

public class MathematicsWrapper {
  private transient long swigCPtr;
  protected transient boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected MathematicsWrapper(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(MathematicsWrapper obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        mathsJNI.delete_MathematicsWrapper(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public MathematicsWrapper() {
    this(mathsJNI.new_MathematicsWrapper(), true);
  }

  public int compute() {
    return mathsJNI.MathematicsWrapper_compute(swigCPtr, this, NumbersVectr.getCPtr(numbers), numbers);
  }
}
```

Swig definition:

```
%module math_module   
%{
    mathematics.h   //contains C++ header for MathematicsWrapper class
                    //so that Java class for MathematicsWrapper can be genereated
%}


%include "std_vector.i"
%template(NumbersVectr) std::vector<int>;
```

Comment: Can you share your SWIG definition as well?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani I just did.

Comment: Looks like whoever built libmath.so forgot to link it against libltdl.

Comment: Does adding 'load_library("libltdl.so");' help?